# How to implement my own federated algorithm Usinsg tensorflow federated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I have read all the documents on the tensorflow federated available at tensorflow.org, but I am not sure how to implement my own federated algorithm. For example, I have a compiled keras model, I know how to convert this to tff.computation. It seems that in order to build a federated algorithm one should build an iterative_process. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file *optimizer_utils.py* in tensorflow federated repo, this file is in the *python/learning/framework/*

More detail, see the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/202c6dbefec09ff884cc37ebd55a1f94e60c74eb/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py#L403)

The function named one_round_computation implements orchestration logic of  federated algorithm in one round. The most import is to build abstract syntax tree using tff.federated_map、tff.federated_broadcast、tff.federated_collect...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code:

`tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(kera_model, dummy_batch)`

Comment: This just compiles your model to tff.learning object. I want to implement my own federated algorithm not my own neural net architecture.